# C# Check if file is at or below a certain level in directory

Tags: c#, string, url, directory, wildcard

I am working with some documents on a web server and I need to do something with them if they are below a certain level in the hierarchy. For instance:

if the structure is like -

```
example.com/region/site1/
example.com/region/site2/ ...etc...
```

I need to act only on files IN ANY FOLDER below below site1/ (but not directly in site1/)

- example.com/region/site1/file.xls - do nothing
- example.com/region/site1/folder/file.xls - do stuff

So far I've been using this function, but I don't know how to use wildcards to get the "any folder below this folder" working.

```
public bool isInWorkingDir(string url)
    {
        bool contains = false;
        string lowerUrl = url.ToLower();

        if (lowerUrl.Contains("nor-am/site1/"))
        {
            contains = true;
        }
        return contains;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you querying the file system to find the file, or do you have a url string and you want to see if that string references a directory below `"site1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically just remove the folder segment from the url, and check if the remaining path still contain a directory separator :

```
public bool IsNestedUnderSubfolder(string url, string folder)
{
    if (!url.StartsWith(folder))
        return false;

    return url.Substring(folder.Length).Contains("/");
}

// False
IsNestedUnderSubfolder("example.com/region/site1/file.xls", "example.com/region/site1/");

// True
IsNestedUnderSubfolder("example.com/region/site1/folder/file.xls", "example.com/region/site1/");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will plug this in and give this a shot today and see how it works out.

Comment: This worked for the question as I posted it. I failed to provide enough detail to account for all the possible scenarios I was facing. My final answer was to check that my string contained the portion of the URL that I needed and then count the number of forward slashes thereafter. It's rudimentary, but it works. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the recursive ProcessDirectory function from the MSDN documentation example (below page).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

List files = new List();

```
public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory.
    string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
    foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
        ProcessFile(fileName);

    // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
    foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
}

// Insert logic for processing found files here.
public static void ProcessFile(string path)
{
    files.Add(path);        
}
```

now call ProcessDirectory with your base path so you can get a list of all files in that folder and its subfolders. Then use Linq:

```
files.Where(f => f.Contains("blabla"));
```

Comment: I didnt downvoted you, but OP was "working with some documents on a web server".

Comment: It's a start. But by itself doesn't solve the OP's problem. It doesn't show how to check that the file is in a directory below the target, and it doesn't show how to break out of the recursion when the file is found. By the way, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: I downvoted for a link only answer earlier, since removed :D

Answer (score 0):

My final code:

```
public bool isInWorkingDir(string url)
    {
        bool inDir = false;
        string lowerUrl = url.ToLower();
        if (lowerUrl.Contains("myRegion/mySite") && countSlash(url)>6)
        {
            inDir = true;
        }
        return inDir;
    }
    public int countSlash(string url)
    {
        int length = url.Length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int n = length - 1; n >= 0; n--)
        {
            if (url[n] == '/')
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```